# LINQ group by with join and count occurence of the same item

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables, one for the **categories** and one for the **products**

They are defined in the following way:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID{get;set;}
    public string ProductName{get;set;}
    public int CompanyID{get;set;}
    public int CategoryID{get;set;}
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID{get;set;}
    public string CategoryName{get;set;}
}
```

The two tables are joined on CategoryID

**I'm trying to get the list of categories with the count of how many companies produce products in that category**

So it's not the count of how many products by category, but how many distinct companies produce product(s) for each category.

I've tried with this query but I'm not able to get it right:

```
var query =
    from c in categories
    join p in products on c.CategoryID equals p.CategoryID
    group c by new {c.CategoryName,p.CompanyID} into cg
    select new
    {
        CatName = cg.Key.CategoryName,
        Count = cg.Count()
    };
```

I've prepared a fiddle ready with sample data here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WHwNFk

The result in the fiddle should be: A=2, B=2, C=2 (so for each category there are 2 different companies that make products in that category)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following LINQ statement will provide you with the results youre looking for. We first have to join our categories to our products on the category ID, then group by the category ID and select the distinct count of company ID

```
 var query = categories.Join(products, 
                             x => x.CategoryID, 
                             z => z.CategoryID, (x, z) => new
                             {
                                  Category = x.CategoryName,
                                  Company = z.CompanyID
                             }).GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => new 
                             {
                                  CatName = x.Key,
                                  Count = x.Distinct().Count()
                             }).ToList();
```

**Output:**

A=2, B=2, C=2

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the expected results; basically you need to add a Distinct to the count and then group again to count the items:

```
var qry =  (from c in categories
            join p in products on c.CategoryID equals p.CategoryID
            group c by new { c.CategoryName, p.CompanyID } into cg
            select new
            {
                CatName = cg.Key.CategoryName,
                Count = cg.Distinct().Count()
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.CatName)
            .Select(y => new { CatName = y.Key, Count = y.Count() });
```